Set default log severity in Application Insight in ASP.NET
I have an application in .net framework 4.8, I'm using Application Insight and TelemetryClient for logging. How can I set the default log severity for the application.
I know in .net core we can set it in appsettings.json like this
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}

But how can we do the same in .net framework?
This is a sample of my code
public class MyLogger
{
    private static TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
    public MyLogger()
    {
     _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
    }

  public void Trace(string message)
  {
     _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Verbose);
  }

  public void Information(string message)
  {    
     _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Information);
  }
}


What do you want to log?

It can be anything, But I want to set the default level to prevent getting lower level logs in Application Insight even if the method has called.

The way you've set the severity logs is correct,
yes, we can set the severity log levels in the class file and then call the method wherever it is required.
I've created an ASP .NET Web App (.NET Framework 4.8), configured Application Insights for it, and successfully observed logs in Application Insights.

In my case, I've created a MyLogger.cs file, where I've defined methods for logging messages with different severity levels. These methods are responsible for specifying the severity level and logging the message accordingly.

In my HomeController.cs, I've simply called the appropriate logging method from MyLogger.cs

By setting the severity levels in the MyLogger.cs file, there will be no need to specify the severity level every time we call the logging method.


This is how I've sent the logs to Application Insights:
I have added a connection string to my ApplicationInsights.config file:
<ConnectionString>Enter your connection</ConnectionString>

According to the comment I've updated the code:
This is my MyLogger.cs:
Here I've set the log level to warning in MyLogger.cs
private static SeverityLevel defaultLogLevel = SeverityLevel.Warning;

using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
namespace Appinsightstest1
{
    public static class MyLogger
    {
        private static readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
        private static SeverityLevel defaultLogLevel = SeverityLevel.Warning;  
        
        public static void LogTrace(string message)
        {
            Log(message, SeverityLevel.Verbose);
        }
        public static void LogWarning(string message)
        {
           Log(message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
        }
        private static void Log(string message, SeverityLevel level)
        {
            if (level >= defaultLogLevel)
            {
                var telemetry = new TraceTelemetry(messagelevel);        
                telemetryClient.TrackTrace(telemetry);
            }
        }
    }
}

My HomeController.cs :
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Appinsightstest1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           MyLogger.LogTrace("This is an Information message from the Controller."); 
           MyLogger.LogWarning("This is a Warning message from the Controller.");           
        return View();
        }   
    }
}

Now, even when I call the trace method, it won't be displayed in App Insights. It only displays the logs with a severity level equal to or higher than the default severity level (in this case, Warning).
Traces in App insights:



Thank you for the response. I have the code you mentioned and it is working for me. What I need is set the default log level in code. e.g. set the log level to warning somewhere in code and even there is a call to trace level it doesn't go to Application insight.

@Mohammad Taherian Please check my updated solution.
